# heatmap.2 function withtout hclustfun(Rowv=FALSE) doesn't end computing

Tags: r

When I use heatmap.2 without hclustfun (Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE), the computing doesn' end permanently.

I have previously found the replacement for development version of gplots works well for this error.

Someone knows?

```
library(gplots)
library(RColorBrewer)
Colv=FALSE; Rowv <- FALSE; dendrogram <- "none"
 colors = c(seq(1,100000,length=101))
 hmcols<- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11,"RdYlBu"))(100)
 hmcols <- hmcols[(c(length(hmcols)):1)]

x <- matrix(1:100000, 5000, 20)

heatmap.2  (x, 
             #hclustfun=hclustfun,
             labCol=NULL, 
             labRow=NULL,
             density.info="none", 
             trace="none", scale="none",
             col=hmcols, 
             breaks=colors,
             symm=F,symkey=F,symbreaks=T,
             Colv=Colv,
             Rowv=Rowv,
             dendrogram=dendrogram,
             )
```

Comment: Can you please show some sample code?  Also, maybe use `dput` to give us a snippet of your data.

Comment: I have add a code.